# Generating @XmlType propOrder default values

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-binding

I want a custom sequence in my `xml response` rather than alphabetical. It's mostly alphabetical order but with few exceptions.
So, I ended up using propOrder in `@XmlType` annotation as a solution.

Now the problem is in few classes I've around 50 fields. Adding a `propOrder` for such classes is hectic to code. If there is anyway `propOrder` values can be generated with default values, lets say in alphabetical order, I will be able change the sequence later.

Any solution would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: For now, I've written a standalone java program to read and load java file provided by the user. Get all the fields using reflection and generate `propOrder` for the same class, reorder it as desired. Please let me know if there is a standard solution for this.